# Why does `bash -c echo hello` not output anything, while `bash -c "echo hello"` output "hello"?

Tags: bash

Why does `bash -c echo hello` not output anything, while `bash -c "echo hello"` output "hello"?

Answer (score 7):

```
bash -c echo hello
```

does output something: a newline. This command instructs Bash to run `echo`, setting $0 to "hello".

```
bash -c "echo hello"
```

on the other hand instructs Bash to run `echo hello`, setting $0 to "bash".

Comment: Thanks. Why does `bash -c "echo $0" hello` output `bash` instead of `hello`, if  `$0` is `hello`?

Comment: When you run `bash -c "echo $0" hello`, `$0` is interpreted by your current shell, not the new `bash`. You can try running that in `zsh` — you'll get `zsh` as output then... `bash -c 'echo $0' hello` will do what you're after.